# How to get previous month with Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure

I'm starting on azure SQL and I want to convert a string into a date and then retrieve the two months before that date.

I tried to use DATEADD(month,-2,sysdatetime()) to get the previous two months but dateadd doesn't work.
"This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database"

Thank you for your help

Comment: what's the string look like?

Comment: Hello ridd, welcome to stack overflow. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi ridd, if you have any other concerns, please let us know, thank you'!

Answer (score 0):

The [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function is supported in Azure SQL database:
[image]

I tested it in my Azure SQL database and it works well:

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = sysdatetime();    
SELECT DATEADD(month,-2,@datetime2) as month
```

[image]

The point is what's the date string look like or where you call the function. Maybe you can share us your whole SQL statements

Here's the official example:

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111';
SELECT 'month',DATEADD(month,1,@datetime2)
```

Hope this helps.